# watch on clientWidth not firing when changing with css

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

TL;DR: If I change the size of a DOM element by css, its directive does not notice this, even if a watch on the size is present.

### Goal

I have a couple of custom directives (`simple-graph`) that each contain an `svg`. I want the one over which the mouse hovers to increase in size. Attempt:

#### 1) css

```
simple-graph       {height: 100px;}
simple-graph:hover {height: 200px;}
```

(This part works.)

#### 2) html

```
<simple-graph ng-repeat="data in datasets" sg-rst="data"></simple-graph>
```

#### 3) directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('simpleGraph', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {rst: '=sgRst'},
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      //Add an svg element to el[0], do initialisation, etc. (not shown)
      //Also, $watch rst to update graph when data is changed. (not shown)

      //Watch size of simple-graph 
      scope.$watch(function(){
        return el[0].clientWidth + el[0].clientHeight;
      }, updateSize);

      function updateSize() {
        //update size of svg element, using el[0].clientHeight and .clientWidth (not shown).
      }
    }
  };
});
```

### Problem / Question

The resize of the `simple-graph` element, caused by the changing height set in the css file, is not noticed by the `scope.$watch` in the directive. **Question: can I somehow force it to fire??**

### Current workaround

1. To the attributes of the simple-graph element (in the html), I've added `sg-hover="hover" ng-mouseenter="hover=true" ng-mouseleave="hover=false"`, which toggles the value of the attribute `sg-hover`, and
2. I funnel this change into the directive by changing its `scope` property to `scope: {rst: '=sgRst', hover: '=sgHover'}` to its `scope`, and
3. I make sure this toggling is noticed by adding a `scope.$watch('hover', updateSize)`.

This works, and shows that the `updateSize` function does indeed work as wanted. But it's terribly elaborate, and I think there must be a faster way. So, again my question: can I somehow force the $watch function to fire when the element client size is changed through css?

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't any event for what you want to do as far as I'm aware, and `scope.$watch`only evaluates when there is a digest cycle, so that is why is not triggering when you change the css class. Check the doc to see examples of how it is supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

As I commented on the question, I don't think you can achieve what you want with the css (at least not in a simple way)

you could change your directive to something like this, at least to avoid repetition:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {rst: '=sgRst'},
    replace: true,
    template: "<div ng-mouseover='hover=true' ng-mouseout:'hover=false' class='simple-graph' ng-class='{hover: hover}'><svg></svg></div>"
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      //create or find the svg element to el[0], do initialisation, etc. (not shown)
      //Also, $watch rst to update graph when data is changed. (not shown)

      //Watch size of simple-graph 
      scope.$watch('hover', updateSize);

      function updateSize() {
        //update size of svg element, using el[0].clientHeight and .clientWidth (not shown).
      }
    }
```

Then change your css to be:

```
.simple-graph .hover {
  height: 200px
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using the template seems like a very good idea to unburden the user. What I can see causing problems though is that this only expands the svg, not its container `simple-graph`... right? (and el[0].clientHeight is read-only if I tested correctly) Also, is there a reason you add the class `simple-hover` to the `svg`?

Comment: sorry, I got confused and thought that was what you were doing. You can then change the template so that you have a container in there too (and optionally set the directive to `replace: true`). I will edit the answer now

Comment: I've tried that, and run into a timing problem it seems. The `$watch` on `hover` fires before the css has had the opportunity to increase the size of the element. Therefore, using `el[0].clientHeight` in the `updateSize()` function uses the wrong size, minimizing the graph when it's hovered over (using the `clientHeight`'s value just before it's updated), and vice versa. The `$watch` on `el[0].clientHeight` (in my original question) doesn't help there either. Any ideas on a workaround?